# Protractor can't find element that has beeen found 2 tests before

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

First timer with protractor. But i got into trouble. Tried to test if an element exists, then if another element is hidden, then  again if the first element is clickable and boooooom...

Protractor hangs responding with `ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with` while the element have been found two tests before. Probably I'm doing something wrong, but what?

```
              describe( 'filters' , function () {                   

                    it ( 'has a .filter-editorial-rating .header' , function ( done ) {
                        element.all( by.css( '.filter-editorial-rating .header' ) )
                            .then( function ( el ) {
                                expect( el.length > 0).toEqual( true );
                                done();
                            });
                    });


                    it( 'ER filter is collapsed by default' , function ( done ) {

                        element.all( by.css ( '.filter-editorial-rating .content.ng-hide' ) )
                            .then( function (el) {
                                expect( el.length > 0).toEqual( true );
                                done();
                            });
                    });

                    it( 'ER filters header is clickable' , function ( done ) {
                        element( by.css( '.filter-editorial-rating .header' ) )
                                .click()   //  <--- hangs with error ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
                                .then( function ( el ) {
                                    done();
                                });
                    });
                });
```

also tried to wrap it in element.all as I did in first place (trying voodoo) but as it thanks god it didn't work. :)

Also I tried to getOuterHtml and I found that the element really exists

this...

```
it( 'ER filters header is clickable' , function ( done ) {
    element( by.css( '.filter-editorial-rating .header' ) )
      .getOuterHtml()
      .then( function ( html ) {
        console.log( html );
        done();
      });
});
```

return's this...

```
 <div class="header" ng-click="collapse.er = !collapse.er">
      <span class="icon icon_plus" ng-show="collapse.er"></span>
      <span class="icon icon_minus ng-hide" ng-show="!collapse.er"></span>

      <h4 class="title"> Star Rating </h4>
 </div>
```

Comment: my only guess would be that the element isn't really visible; the first 2 tests check that the element is in the DOM, but the only test that actually interacts with it is the failing one. you can verify this by trying to `click()` / `sendText()` or something else in the previous 2 tests and verify that those fail as well

Comment: to check if an element is visible, use `.isDisplayed()`. if you want to check if it's in the DOM, use `.isPresent()`.

Comment: I changed the first two test to `isDisplayed()` because that was the right way for testing if an element exists and is visible at the same time. while `isDisplayed()` return's true the element is not interactable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOOOk... my bad

setting in config.js in the `onPrepare()` methofd the window size fixed the problem.
there was a media query doing tricks with the container of that element.

```
var width = 1024;
var height = 600;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```